# To replace the line on which regex found with content of file which name is in regex captured

Tags: sed

How to get content of file which name is obtained by regex, to be inserted by way of replacing that line, within the sed's applied file?
e.g. illustration

```
$ sed -E '/^file:\s*(\S+)/ r"\1"' file.txt
```

try to have content of file as visible string found following `file:` to replace the line where regex matches inside the `file.txt`

Comment: Can you please show what the input line looks like and how it should be changed?

Comment: There is no way to do this entirely within a `sed` script. Probably switch to a simple preprocessor which lets you include files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^file:\s*(\S+).*/{p;s//cat "\1"/e}' file
```

Print the line matching the regexp and then evaluate the command `cat` on the first back-reference.

If the matching line is not needed, then a substitution is suffice:

```
sed -E 's/^file:\s*(\S+).*/cat "\1"/e' file
```